# Valid proof for f(A*B) = f(A) * f(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> **Given**
>
> $\mathbb{F}$ is a field. Let $f\colon M_{22}(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$ be a transformation defined by $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \to a + d$ for all $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in M_{22}(\mathbb{F})$
>
> (This is a trace map as someone pointed out in my earlier question)
>
> Prove for all $A, B \in M_{22}(\mathbb{F}): f(AB) = f(A) f(B)$

**Amateur tries to prove**

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = A$

$f(A) f(B) = (a + d)(a + d) = a^2 + 2(ad) + d^2$

$AB = \begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc & ab+bd\\\ ac+dc & bc + d^2\end{pmatrix}$

$f(AB) = (a^2 + bc) + (bc + d^2) = a^2 + 2(bc) + d^2$

$f(A)f(B) = f(AB) \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$

Therefore, $f(A)f(B) = f(AB)$ is not generally true. $\Box$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT** 
Great job arguing the statement was false.

However, I think the intent was to show $f(A+B) = f(A)+f(B)$ which works out well.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment! To show that f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B) is the next part of the assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

The disproof is correct and the statement is false.

In fact, $f(A) + f(B) = f(A+B)$ would hold and im sure you could immediately see this